# Why list of pd.Interval doesn't recognized by DataFrame automatically?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, intervals

```py
intervals = [pd.Interval(0, 0.1), pd.Interval(1, 5)]
pd.DataFrame({'d':intervals}).dtypes
```

Produces dtype as *Object* not *Interval*:

```py
>>> d    object
>>> dtype: object
```

But at the same time list of, for example, DateTimes is recognized on the fly:

```py
datetimes = [pd.Timestamp('2013-01-02'), pd.Timestamp('2016-10-20')]
pd.DataFrame({'d':datetimes}).dtypes
>>> d    datetime64[ns]
>>> dtype: object
```

Is situation with `intervals` somewhat like with list of `strings` - default type of column in the DataFrame will be `object` as well, because DataFrame doesn't 'know' if we want to treat this column as objects (for dumping to disk, ..), or as strings (for concatenation, ..) or even as elements of category type? If so - what different use cases with `intervals` may be? If not what is the case here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in pandas: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23563

For now, the cleanest workaround is to wrap the list with `pd.array`:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd; pd.__version__
Out[1]: '0.24.2'

In [2]: intervals = [pd.Interval(0, 0.1), pd.Interval(1, 5)]

In [3]: pd.DataFrame({'d': pd.array(intervals)}).dtypes
Out[3]:
d    interval[float64]
dtype: object
```